# use jrebel and kumuluz

Tags: java, jrebel

I tried using jrebel in netbeans with kumuluz, but I am having difficulty integrating it, I followed the lines on the next page:
https://manuals.jrebel.com/jrebel/standalone/maven.html

I have also tried removing kumuluz jetty server (https://ee.kumuluz.com/) and running it independently and using maven (https://manuals.jrebel.com/jrebel/standalone/launch-from-command -line.html # jettycli), but got no results.

my last attempt was to use agentpath with jrebel path and main com.kumuluz.ee.EeApplication file location but it doesn't work.

I use this simple example: https://github.com/kumuluz/kumuluzee-samples/tree/master/jax-rs

Comment: Please elaborate at which configuration step you are getting stuck. "doesn't work" isn't very specific. Does the banner show up when adding the agent? Does it show a console message like "Directory 'x' will be monitored"? Does it not reload when making changes? What type of changes?

Comment: JRebel works correctly, it is integrated in the IDE (Netbeans in this case), the java project with maven has the file `rebel.xml`, use the `command mvn clean package && java -jar target / example.jar` to deploy inside a dock server (provided by the framework), how can you use jrebel before using commands? Does JRebel have the capacity?
See the official documentation on the Spring Boot case (https://manuals.jrebel.com/jrebel/standalone/springboot.html) added the argument: `mvn spring-boot: run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments = "- agentpath:[path]"`, is it possible to use a similar command line?

Comment: `java -agentpath:[path] -jar target/example.jar`